# YAML Azure Pipelines - Loops with Conditional Jobs

Tags: yaml, terragrunt

I have the following YAML pipeline that I cannot seem to get working based on the conditional values.

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: "workloads"
    type: object
    default:
      wkld001: update
      wkld002: "delete"
      wkld003: "update"
      wkld004: "update"
      wkld005: "update"
      wkld006: "update"
  - name: "environment"
    type: string
    values:
      - prd
      - dev
  - name: "landing_zone"
    type: string
    values:
      - private
      - integration

stages:
  - stage: 
    jobs:
    - job: create_params
      steps:
      - powershell: |
          write-host "test"   
    - ${{each item in parameters.workloads}}:
      - ${{ if eq(parameters.workloads[item.key].value, 'update') }}:
        - job: "${{item.key}}"
          dependsOn: create_params
          steps:
            - powershell: |
                write-host "testing loop - ${{item.value}}"
```

What i want to do is have a specific command run based on the value set for the workload map.

When I run the above no conditions are met so only the pre-job runs.

The expected behaviour is the loop runs, and the right job is spawned based on the map conditions.

The example only shows the "update" condition only; I plan to have a few more.

Answer (score 0):

I got  there in the end with this.

```yaml
pool:
  name: "UOLUKSSHPOOL01"

parameters:
  - name: "workloads"
    type: object
    default:
      wkld001: update
      wkld002: "delete"
      wkld003: "update"
      wkld004: "update"
      wkld005: "update"
      wkld006: "update"
  - name: "environment"
    type: string
    values:
      - prd
      - dev
  - name: "landing_zone"
    type: string
    values:
      - private
      - integration

stages:
  - stage: 
    jobs:
    - job: create_params
      steps:
      - powershell: |
          write-host "test"   
    - ${{each item in parameters.workloads}}:
      - ${{ if eq(item.value, 'update') }}:
        - job: "${{item.key}}"
          condition: 
          dependsOn: create_params
          steps:
            - powershell: |
                write-host "testing loop - ${{item.value}}"
```